# Merge 2 tables and get other tables value if exists (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got 2 table

```
levels
--------
id
owner_id
level
name

owner
--------------
id
name
```

An owner can add their own levels name on `levels table`. By default levels table has 10 rows with `owner_id = 0`.

Let's say owner add `level 2` value to `levels table`. How can I still get all (10 rows) the default value but change the `level 2` default value to using owner value?

I've tried to using:

```
$query = Levels:with('owner')->get();
```

But it only get owner value without the default value.

---

Curernt solution:

```
$lists = Level::where('owner_id', $owner_id)->lists('level');

$owner= Level::where('owner_id', $owner_id)->get();
$default = Level::whereNotIn('level', $lists)->get();

$levels = $default->merge($owner)->sortBy('level')->all();

return $levels;
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with *"..but change the `level 2` default value to using owner value ?"* using `Levels::with('owner')->get();` should result in you had level instance (11 of them) with their related owner, in your case the first 10 rows (default levels) had null relation regarding `owner`.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. what i mean is, when i Query i want to change the default value of `level 2` to using owner `level 2 value` (if exists). if its not exist still query the default value. RIght now i can query it but using a long way.

Comment: how is your current query?

Comment: @Tezla I've update my question with my current solution

Comment: @Tezla different between default and owner is. `$owner` only query "level that owner add". and `$default` is all the listing default level exclude "owner level"

Comment: well, `whereIn` should return all item that mentioned in the parameter. on the other hand, [`whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNotIn) excludes. so far, i can't think of shorter method than your approach.

Comment: @Tezla ah yes. it should be `whereNotIn` my bad. My mistake. So do you got any solution to make it shorter, without query it 4 times?

Comment: well instead of `->lists('level')` to build an array of existing level you can simply iterate your `Level::where('owner_id', $owner_id)->get()` query results to get ids and push it to temporary array.